# XML DTD Validate. Difference in Eclipse and other editors

Tags: xml, eclipse, validation, dtd

I have XML with inline DTD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE why [
<!ELEMENT why (animal,weight,age) >
]>  
<why>
 <animal>giraffe</animal>
 <weight>1192</weight>
 <age>26</age>
</why>
```

Eclipse completes validation with no errors or warnings.
But other editors find errors of course. I'm agree with other editors))

Why does Eclipse work this way? Autocomplete? I wonder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE why [
<!ELEMENT why (animal,weight,age) >
<!ELEMENT animal (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT weight (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT age (#PCDATA)>
]>  
<why>
 <animal>giraffe</animal>
 <weight>1192</weight>
 <age>26</age>
</why>
```

You can validate your xml-dtd whit this page : 
http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_upload

Comment: You're right, but Eclipse validate my file. Only Eclipse and program based on Eclipse.

Comment: Eclipse not autocomplete dtd's. You need a page for validate your code.